# Where Clause with IN and Coalesce

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table, Music:

```
Genre          Artist              Song
Rock           Rolling Stones      Brown Sugar 
Rock           Bob Seger           Night Moves
Country        Eric Church         Record Year
Pop            Bruno Mars          Grenade
```

And I have

```
DECLARE @Genre VarChar(MAX) = NULL
DECLARE @Artist VarChar(MAX) = NULL

SELECT *
FROM Music M
WHERE (M.Genre = COALESCE(@Genre, M.Genre) OR
M.Artist = COALESCE(@Artist, M.Artist))
```

This gives me the option to chose a genre and add a random artist that I would also like to see.

But what if I want to pass in multiple Artists as a string,
i.e.

```
@Genre = Rock
@Artist = 'Eric Church, Bruno Mars'
```

where in essence I would need an IN statement but also have to handle instances where the variable is NULL?

I am using SQL SERVER.

Thank you

Comment: Consider using a string splitting function, e.g.: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: You want `AND` rather than `OR`. Otherwise, passing `NULL` to either field will return all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can use CHARINDEX, but it performance is low.

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM Music M
   WHERE CHARINDEX(','+M.Genre+',',','+@Genre+',' ) >0 OR CHARINDEX(','+M.Artist+',',','+@Artist+',' ) >0
   ```
2. Dynamic statement：

   ```
   DECLARE @Genre VarChar(MAX) = NULL
   DECLARE @Artist VarChar(MAX) = NULL
   DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)
   SET @sql='
         SELECT * 
         FROM Music M
         WHERE M.Genre in ('+@Genre+') OR M.Artist in ('+@Artist+')'
   EXEC(@sql)
   ```
3. using split string function
4. Handling the NULL,you can change statement to.

   ```
    SET @sql='
         SELECT * 
         FROM Music M
         WHERE M.Genre in ('+ISNULL(@Genre,'M.Genre')+') OR M.Artist in ('+ISNULL(@Artist,'M.Artist')+')'
   ```

When @Genre and @Artist is null, the script will be below:

```
SELECT * FROM Music M
WHERE M.Genre in (M.Genre) OR M.Artist in (M.Artist)'
```

1 in (1) always be true

Comment: hi Nolan, would using the dynamic statement handle null cases well? You see I used coalesce to return all if nothing is passed

Comment: Does No.4 is helpful for you?

Answer (score 1):

**Using a Parse/Split function**

```
Declare @Artist varchar(max) = 'Eric Church,Bruno Mars'
Declare @Genre  varchar(max) = 'Rock'

Select Distinct A.*
  From YourTable A
  Join (
         Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@Artist,',') 
         Union All
         Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@Genre,',') 
       ) B on A.Artist = B.RetVal or A.Genre=B.RetVal
```

Returns

```
Genre       Artist          Song
Country     Eric Church     Record Year
Pop         Bruno Mars      Grenade
Rock        Bob Seger       Night Moves
Rock        Rolling Stones  Brown Sugar
```

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```